# Remote link_to is requesting html instead of js

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to make it so when you click on a link it appends some information about a post on the same page without reloading that page. The way I achieve this is using jQuery. So I setup `<%= link_to posts_controller(post), remote: true %>` with a show.js.erb in my views. This doesn't work because it is simply sending me to the html page and not responding to the JavaScript. This is requesting using GET and not POST.

I've tried adding and removing `rails-ujs` and `jquery_ujs` from my `application.js`, made it so the button sends you to the JavaScript format of it (just shows raw JavaScript though), I've tried using different versions of jQuery (jQuery 1 and 3), and removing and adding `<%= javascript_include_tag :jquery %>` from my `application.html.erb`

I have added

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
end
```

to my controller. I do have `//= require jquery3` and `//= require jquery_ujs` in my `application.js`

I have added `alert('sumthing');` to my `show.js.erb`, but nothing showed up when clicking on the link, giving me the conclusion that something is wrong with either jQuery or the way that I setup my link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what was wrong. It was that for rails 6 you have to use the web packer version of jQuery. I figured out how to install this using [this helpful guide.](https://www.botreetechnologies.com/blog/rails-6-jquery-upgrade-with-webpacker/) Also thanks to educ_gt for leading me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your rails application does not have javascript_include_tag (or javascript_pack_tag) as you think. POST method in rails application can be worked by javascript, correctly.

If your rails application version is 6, you should use javascript_pack_tag in application.html.erb.

Probably, in web browser console, you can find some kind of errors which are associated with javascript reading.

You should check it.

Comment: I have ```<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>``` in my ```application.html.erb``` but that is it. I only got warnings in my web browser console and they were all about "Cookie "key" will be soon treated as cross-site cookie".

Comment: I assume that your application does not read javascript file. Does your application have application.js under javascript/packs directory ?

Comment: Interesting. My application does have application.js. I have added jquery3 and jquery_ujs in application.js

Comment: The application.js is under packs directory? I assume that your application can't read all javascript files. In rails 6, the application read javascript files through webpacker by default.

Comment: Yes under the packs directory. Should I try installing jQuery to my webpacker?

Comment: Thank you!
> Should I try installing jQuery to my webpacker?

Yes, you should do (Correctly, you should install rails/ujs).
```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
```
I think the application.js under packs directory is like this. 

If your application.js has this code, all you have to do is installing webpacker i think.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I'll add an answer for this.